# How can I fix jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid when using the Link component in React?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

In a React app

```js
<Link to={`/person/${person.id}`}>Person Link</Link>
```

results in the following eslint error

`The href attribute is required on an anchor. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid`

The Link component results in a valid `href` attribute.

```js
<a href="#/person/2">Person Link</a>
```

What is the point of this error? How do I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `Link` component generates `href` attribute so in the end anchor tag is valid from the accessibility point of view. Add [an exception](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md#rule-details) to `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
      "components": [ "Link" ],
      "specialLink": [ "to" ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Additionally, there is the same issue with a answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/340).

Comment: I get that, but why is the error reported in the first place? The rule must have been made to explicitly check this component, right?

Comment: @ErictheRed Seems like it doesn't and it has to be explicitly stated that component uses some other prop to render `href` attribute. I agree that's not the full answer to your question.

Comment: When having Next.js this will help you out:  

```"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": ["error", {  
     "components": ["Link"],  
     "specialLink": ["hrefLeft", "hrefRight"],  
     "aspects": ["invalidHref", "preferButton"]  
}]```

Comment: Thanks, @LaurisKuznecovs your answer worked for me

Answer (score 3):

As per they suggest in the https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md

you can do the following:
call the link component with  tag inside of it, as per in nextjs docs.
then, you can simply use the passHref prop in the Link component, and add a dummy href attribute in the  tag

Something like this:

```
<Link to={`/person/${person.id}`} passHref> <a href="replace">Person Link</a></Link>
```

It should do the trick :)
The eslint ignore rules suggested above didn't work for me, btw, but this solution did, and it's one of the recommended ones in the docs about the rule.

Comment: Nice answer. Works a treat. FYI the exact location where they talk about this wrt NextJs is here https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md#case-i-use-nextjs-and-im-getting-this-error-inside-of-links

Answer (score -1):

adding this in my `.eslintrc` file in setting  > rules fixed the issue

```js
"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [
      "off",
      {
        "components": ["Link"],
        "specialLink": ["hrefLeft", "hrefRight"],
        "aspects": ["noHref", "invalidHref", "preferButton"]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score -15):

Perhaps you meant to put backticks instead of single-quotes in order to create a template literal. Try the following:

```
<Link to={`/person/${this.state.id}/edit`}>Edit</Link>
```

Answer (score -15):

you can just write some text content inside the "a" tag and hide it with CSS (font-size:0px or something