# React site warning: The href attribute requires a valid address. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, anchor

I am getting a warning on a React site I built

```
./src/components/layout/Navbar.js [1]   Line 31:  The href attribute requires a valid 
address. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
```

on the following code:

```
          <p>
            {isEmpty(profile.website) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={profile.website}
                target="#"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-globe fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}
            {isEmpty(profile.social && profile.social.twitter) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={profile.social.twitter}
                target="#"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}
            {isEmpty(profile.social && profile.social.facebook) ? null : (
              <a
                className="text-white p-2"
                href={profile.social.facebook}
                target="#"
              >
                <i className="fab fa-facebook fa-2x" />
              </a>
            )}
          </p>
```

Even though the warning appears only for the first link, the same warning occurs on the next link if I remove the first link temporarily or change the href of the first link to a static URL.

The links need to appear as just an icon.

I have tried things such as using a button (did not have the correct look), using a function to open the dynamic url, and trying to force the href to be a string by using `'' + {profile.website}`. Many other suggestions have not worked.

Is there a way to prevent the error, without changing the jsx-a11y rules? Is what I have done not a good pattern, or is it just a bug in React or JSX?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing your expression with quotes?

Comment: I tried using single and double quotes and backticks, it was not valid. If you could provide an example I will try it again, I may have not had them correct!

Comment: Use `{profile.website || '#'}`

Answer (score 202):

Use `href="/#"` to replace `href="#"` OR `href="javascript:;"` OR `href="javascript:void(0);"`

It should remove the warnings.

Comment: the javascript trick doesn't seem to work in eslint 7.0.0
`The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles.`

Comment: The JS community... Shouldn't we at least wonder what the warning is about and discuss the implications of side-stepping it?

Comment: And instead of using a hack to suppress the warning, why not simply tell the linter `// eslint-disable-next-line` on that particular line?

Comment: This seems to be a silly warning for anchor links.

Answer (score 37):

These worked for me to get rid off the warning;

```
<a href="#/">...</a>  
<a href={() => false}>...</a>
```

Comment: Or just `<a href="/">...</a>`.

Comment: No yuri that would redirect to root not deny to redirect

Answer (score 23):

I've used `href="!#"` to remove warnings.

Comment: As I tried this Ive noticed that it is forcing page to render totally. So Ive used href="#!"

Answer (score 18):

This is just a warning not a error that href attribute requires a valid value as # points to nowhere you can add links to href attributes to remove this warnings or if you are still in early development phase just write

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
```

On top of your code it will remove the warnings from the terminal, the above line disables the rule for the specified file where it is written

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React from 'react';

const Header = () =>{
    return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
         )
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can have the above solution in my eslint rules?

Comment: you want the eslint rules should appear in your console

Comment: I just wanted to know how to confugure it on my eslint rules and i already go the solution

Comment: Give a path to href then it will not show this eslint rules or put the comment as shown in the above solution

Answer (score 17):

To also prevent default I use this:

```
<a href="/#" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 14):

Insert space after # so no more warning about it

replace `href="#"` to `href="# "`
but better if use like that `href="#something"` => `href="#profile"`

Comment: "# " It works but it is sooooo ugly. Always is good to have options so thank you!

Answer (score 12):

please use `<button>` instead of `<a>` when there's no `href` attribute.

[official reference](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md)

If you really have to use the `a` tag, it maybe help you:

```js
<a href="#" onClick={ev => {ev.preventDefault(); onClick();}}>"Hello A Tag"</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

try replacing

```
target="#"
```

to

```
target="_blank"
```

Comment: this seems to be much cleaner approach

Answer (score 7):

I got the similar warning for href, I did as follows. May be try this. I got rid of the warning and functionality is intact. I am not sure this is correct. But tried this.

```
let hrefLink = '#'; passed as a arg like href={hrefLink}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to render a page link dynamically then you can switch out an `<a>` tag for a `<div>` tag instead. The warning message will go away.

```
// DON't DO THiS
<a className="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}>
  {page}
</a>;

// TRY THIS INSTEAD
<div className="page-link" onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}>
  {page}
</div>;
```

If you put "javascript" word in the href attribute then you will get a **RED WARNING**:

> index.js:1375 Warning: A future version of React will block
>   javascript: URLs as a security precaution. Use event handlers instead
>   if you can.

Reference: [EsLint error resolution page](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md)

Answer (score 5):

I've used the href in tag a. it's remove warnings.

```
<a href>Pictures</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You also can hide this warning adding a `eslint-disable-next-line` comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
<a
    onClick={e => {
        // do something
    }}
>
    example
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following to remove warnings.

```
<a href="/">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. A lot of times, people not only want an answer, but to learn why their mistake existed in the first place.  Could you please elaborate on your answer so the OP and others can learn?

Answer (score 1):

**If we have written correct url but it also gives the same error like I put [www.reactjs.org](http://www.reactjs.org) then it also gives the same warning. To resolve these problem we have an attribute in anchor tag i.e.**

```
<a
   className="App-link"
   href="https://reactjs.org"
   target="_blank"
   rel="noopener noreferrer"
    >
      Learn React
    </a>
```

1. className used for style.
2. href used for links.
3. target used for open a link into new tab or not.
4. Rel is used to outcome from that warning in react.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see something wrong if I'm refering to this.
https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md

Check in these links. Some people had the same problem than you and it comes from a Link component. They fix it in adding an exception to .eslintrc:

first link => https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/340
and the second link => [How can I fix jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid when using the Link component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875730/how-can-i-fix-jsx-a11y-anchor-is-valid-when-using-the-link-component-in-react)

Let me know if it's helping.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but surprised no one recommended `window.location`, which simply sets the same exact route as the current?

Other solutions such as **"#"**, **"/#"**, and **"/"** actually modify the current route right?  For a more generic solution just use `window.location` to stay on the current page without modification.

---

```
<a href="window.location" onClick={...}> Better Solution </a>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your anchor  tag to have an onClick method you must use a valid href link orelse it will throw an error , The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible.  If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles.

Change you button style with this property to make transparent

```
button{
        background-color: Transparent;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        border: none;
        cursor:pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        outline:none;
}
```

and set the text inside the button to the resemble link color

I have use this color

```
.editcolor{
        color: #1890ff;
}
```

I resolved my errors with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried but most of the answers above did not work for me since the newer eslint does not allow most of them. Instead, it mentions disabling eslint for the specific line.

Simply add: 
`// eslint-disable-next-line`
 to the line which comes just before the jsx line that throws error.

Also, add this comment within {/* ... */} else it will show error.

Usage: `{/* // eslint-disable-next-line */ }}`

They advise the same thing:
[image: screenshot of error]

Hope this solves it!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change "#" to "# ". Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```js
  <li className="nav-item pointer">
     <a onClick={logout} href="/#"  className="nav-link">
        LOGOUT
     </a>
  </li>
```

or just use

href="/"

Answer (score 0):

Do Not Use: `<a href='#'>Something</a>` but instead use: `<a href='/'>Something</a>`