# eslint fails on <a> inside <Link> in React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, next.js

I got Next.js React app. Here is my code:

```
<Link href="/foo">
  <a>Bar</a>
</Link>
```

eslint tells me this:
`The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible.`
But Next.js wants me to inculde an `a` tag inside my `Link`. Ho do I configure eslint properly or change my code so that it doesn't warn me about this? Aside from completely disabling this rule of course.

Comment: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/402 You can find a workaround there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid when using the Link component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875730/how-can-i-fix-jsx-a11y-anchor-is-valid-when-using-the-link-component-in-react)

Comment: @biw The question is similar but it's not at all the same. I got `a` inside `Link`. They got only `Link`. Their solution does not apply for my situation. Look at the code. Why do you vote for close without diving into the details?

Comment: My apologies @Gherman! I should not have voted to close. It is not the same and I see that now.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to .eslintrc.json

```
"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
        "components": [ "Link" ],
        "specialLink": [ "hrefLeft", "hrefRight" ],
        "aspects": [ "invalidHref", "preferButton" ]
    }]
```

This setting control the error.
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid`

if you are using vscode just right click on the warning in PROBLEMS and you can check if disable only for that lino or the entire file

Comment: I want to disable it for all `a` inside of `Link`s. Otherwise it's not much of a fix

Comment: this is still open question. Also github has allot issues not solved about the same problem. Suggestion - wait a bit more :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875838/2840324 

Answer (score 0):

For NextJS adding `"react-app"` to extends helped.

```
"extends": [
    ...
    "react-app"
],
```